# Login page fails to load resource after clicking sign in

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, authentication, axios

I have a login page created with VueJS and Laravel, my VueJS runs at http://localhost:5173 and my Laravel runs at http://127.0.0.1:8000, after giving the credentials in login page it throws error of
Login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is the code for axios.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store'


const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
})

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(config=>{
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.user.token}`
    return config;
})

export default axiosClient;
```

This is the store index.js:

```
import {createStore} from "vuex";
import axiosClient from "../axios";

const store = createStore({
    state:{
            user:{
                data:{},
                      token: sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
                },
            
            },

    getters:{},
    actions:{
        register({commit}, user){
            return axiosClient.post('/register', user)
              .then(({data}) => {
              commit('setUser', data);
              return data;
            })
      
    },
        login({commit}, user) {
            return axiosClient.post('/login', user)
               .then(({data}) => {
                commit('setUser', data);
                return data;
              })
          }
    },
    mutations:{
        logout: (state)=>{
             state.user.data={};
            state.user.token=null;
         },

        setUser: (state, userData) =>{
            state.user.data = userData.data;
            state.user.token = userData.token;
            sessionStorage.setItem('TOKEN', userData.token);
        }
    },
     modules:{}
})

export default store;
```

This is the  part of login component in vue:

```
 <script setup>
 import { LockClosedIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/solid'
 import store from '../store'
 import {useRouter} from 'vue-router'

 const router = useRouter();
 const user = {
 email:'',
 password:'',
 remember:false
 }


 function login(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();

  store.dispatch('login', user).then((res)=>{router.push({name: 'Dashboard'})});

  }

  </script>
```

This is the router index.js:

```
 import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";

import DefaultLayout from '../components/DefaultLayout.vue';
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';
import Survey from '../views/Surveys.vue';
import Register from '../views/Register.vue';
import store from '../store';
import AuthLayout from '../components/AuthLayout.vue'

const routes =[
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/dashboard',
        component: DefaultLayout,
        meta:{requiresAuth:true},
        children: [{
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component: Dashboard
        }, {path:'/Surveys', name:'Surveys', component:Survey}]},

        {
            path: '/Auth',
            redirect: '/Login',
            component: AuthLayout,
            meta: {isGuest:true},
            children: [{
                path: '/Login',
                name: 'Login',
                component: Login
            },
            {
                path: '/Register',
                name: 'Register',
                component: Register 
            }]
        }
        ]




const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.state.user.token){
        next({name: 'Login'});
    }
    else if(store.state.user.token && to.meta.isGuest){
        next({name:'Dashboard'});
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
})

export default router;
```

This is router api.php:

```
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMzxP.png)

Comment: Is `/login` in router routes?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the code and included that part also

Answer (score 0):

I think your axios config is wrong.

Base url must ref to BE endpoint

The url must: http://127.0.0.1:8000

change in axios.js to:

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
})
```

Comment: I changed the base URL and now it gives the following error: Login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: try change from  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' to 'localhost::8000'